# Проблема с синтаксисом

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax

Не понимаю, что нужно, пишет Invalid syntax
Подскажите пожалуйста

```
ycl = ([1 if (ycl[0], ycl[1]) > 0.0 and ycl[2] = 1 else 0 for ycl in ycl])
```

когда добавляю `and ycl[2] = 1`, сразу выдает ошибку
если убираю, ошибок нет, все принимает, но без этой переменной никак

Comment: Если подразумевается проверка на равенство, то нужно писать `==`. Одинарное `=` - это присваивание. Обычное присваивание внутри такого выражения работать не будет, только через оператор "моржика" `:=`.

Comment: Да, действительно. Благодарю.